# FreeBSD rootfs in 32MB RAM?

Tags: freebsd, bsd

How to build a FreeBSD rootfs from scratch that can be mounted in RAM? This rootfs will be mounted right after the kernel is loaded in the system. The desired filesystem is UFS and then the RAM capacity is 32MB as this is an embedded system. The kernel is already flashed in a 4MB flash memory and I have no more problem with it as it booted successfully in my device. Only the part on mounting the rootfs filesystem so that I can perform Unix commands making the system usable.

I've tried using memory disk as described in [md(4) manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=md&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) together with [mdconfig(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?mdconfig(8)) but seems my initial try-out doesn't work. Just maybe I have not understood it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this with [mdmfs](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdmfs&sektion=8).
There is also a manual in the handbook [https://people.freebsd.org/~rodrigc/doc/handbook/disks-virtual.html](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Erodrigc/doc/handbook/disks-virtual.html)